# Multimeter Range and Resolution

Tags: dc, multimeter, probe, accuracy

I'm confused as to how my multimeter takes readings, especially since its not an auto-range multimeter.  I have to switch to the desired range to carry out measurements. Unfortunately, the resolution part is what confuses me. How do I know my exact reading?

[image]

Comment: Just remember that as soon as you connect ANY measuring device to a circuit, you alter the circuit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your meter uses a DVM, digital voltmeter, module with a range of -199.9 mV to +199.9 mV (or ±0.2 V in round numbers). These are known as 3½-digit displays, the leading '1' being the ½ digit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fV2TSs.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Simplified switching diagram for current measurement ranges. Only one switch closed at a time but make-before-break contacts are likely to be used to prevent high voltages being applied to the DVM during range switching. Fuses and input protection not shown.*

The current measurement ranges connect the digital display inputs across a current shunt resistor whose value will generate a 200 mV drop at the rated current. So, most sensitive range on your meter, 2 mA full-scale, will need a resistor of \$ R = \frac V I = \frac {0.2}{0.002} = 100\ \Omega\$ for the current shunt. The resolution of the display is the smallest increment it can display on that range.

```
Range:  2.000 mA    20.00 mA    200.0 mA     2.000 A
            |           |           |            |
Resolution: 1 μA        10 μA       100 μA       1 mA
```

As Andy has noted the *accuracy* depends on the stack-up of all the errors.

Answer (score 5):

> *Unfortunately, the resolution part is what confuses me.*

Resolution is the smallest increment that your display can indicate. In other words, if you are on the 2 mA range then the display will be like 1.000 mA when 1 mA is being measured. The least significant digit is 1 μA.

But, the accuracy (1.2%) tells you that if your display reads 1.000 mA then the meter might be actually be measuring a current between 0.988 mA and 1.012 mA. But, it's a bit worse than that because the text says something like this: `1.2% + 2`.

The `+ 2` bit means that the least significant digit could be in error by up to 2 in either direction. So now, if 1 mA was fed to the meter, it might read anything from 0.986 mA to 1.014 mA.

Clearly, if you are only measuring 100 μA, the `+ 2` bit becomes ten times more significant as an error. For instance, if the current through your meter was exactly 0 mA then the display might indicate a value of -0.002 mA to +0.002 mA.

> *So how do i know my exact reading?*

You don't and, neither does anyone else. There are always measurement and rounding errors.